# Can you prorate the standard deduction as a dual-status alien in the United States?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs

[According to the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxation-of-dual-status-aliens):

"You cannot use the standard deduction allowed on Form 1040, U.S. Individual Income Tax Return. However, you can itemize certain allowable deductions."

Does this mean I am not allowed to use it at all, or am I allowed to prorate the standard deduction depending on the percentage of time I was in the U.S. as a tax resident out of 365 days?

Comment: On what basis do you claim to be a dual-status alien? You pass the Green Card Test or Substantial Presence Test but this is your first or last year of residence?

Comment: If you are a dual-status alien, you cannot use the standard deduction at all. However, if you are married, and you or your spouse is a resident at the end of the year, you guys can choose to use the [Choosing Resident Alien Status](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2022_publink1000222177) or [Noresident Spouse Treated as Resident](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2022_publink1000222193) elections, both of which will make both of you residents for the whole year, and make you guys file jointly. In that case you will be able to use the standard deduction.

Comment: @user102008 I pass the Substantial Presence Test but this is my last year of residence

Comment: By default the residency termination date is Dec 31. Are you submitting a statement to establish an earlier residency termination date?

Comment: @user102008 Yes, I plan on doing that. I believe the due date is next year in 2024, alongside my final return, correct?

Comment: Why not just leave the residency termination date at Dec 31, which means you are resident the whole year and can use the standard deduction, and then you can use the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion and/or Foreign Tax Credit to exclude the US tax from the part of the year after you leave? (The Foreign Tax Credit will pro-rate your standard deduction based on how your income is divided between countries.)

Comment: @user102008 That is an interesting proposal. My income exclusively comes from buying and selling US stocks. I might consider filing as a full-year USA resident and a full-year CDN non-resident, then. By the way, what do you mean with your last sentence "The Foreign Tax Credit will pro-rate your standard deduction based on how your income..."? Do you have a source link by any chance?

Comment: @user102008 What lured me to Canada in the first place was their policy of taxing only 50% of capital gains, as opposed to the USA, which taxes the full 100%. I'm also hoping that the move will reset my income tax bracket, for example, a high tax bracket for the USA side from January 1 to June 1, and a low tax bracket for the CDN side from June 1 to December 31.

Comment: See Form 1116. On line 3c you calculate the standard/itemized deductions and other deductions. On line 3f you calculate the percentage of that country's income out of all your income. You multiply those, so line 3g is a prorated amount of standard deduction is allocated to that country's income, and this will reduce the amount of Foreign Tax Credit you can get for that country. So you will not get any benefit from the portion of your standard deduction that is allocated to that country's income, and you will only get a deduction from the portion that is allocated to US income.